# Chrome is compositing layers without triggering repaint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging a canvas library I'm working on, i encountered, that chrome-devtools keep reporting "composite layers" and "update layer tree" every animationframe, without repainting or moving any objects.

An example:

```
var x = 0;
( function tick( ) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    x++;
}( ) )
```

These operations are not time intensive ( 0.005 - 0.05 ms each frame ), but I would like to know why this is happening.

The only idea coming to my mind, is that chrome uses something similar to:

```
console.time( "composite layers" );
// do compositing    
for( var i = 0; i < compositedLayers.length; ++i ) {
   // not triggered since compositedLayers.length = 0
   // but takes some time to be checked
   compositedLayers[i].composite();
}
console.timeEnd( "composite layers" );
```

So if this is the case, why "Paint", "Recalculate Style", "Layout",... are not triggered the same way?

**Update:**

- This happens in Chrome 36/37 (Windows)
- On Chromium 34 (Linux) it only displays composite layers
- other systems untested

**Edit1:**
This only occurs when using `requestAnimationFrame`. `setInterval` only shows timer fired, as expected.

**Edit2:**
Complete Source Code of the example: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eMuPg67a)

Comment: did u try to $ trigger(resize) ?

Comment: look at the link of the edit, it's the complete sourcecode. No jQuery, no other libraries, no DOM manipulation, no canvas, nothing.

Comment: But you're not doing anything with the DOM so why should it? **EDIT:** oh sorry didn't read it right, but since you request an animationframe it is supposed to do this right?

Comment: Thats exactly my question... shouldn't rAF act like `setInterval`?

Comment: What i meant was can you trigger resize event . and then see if it repaints.

Comment: it does, but the problem is, chrome does repaint, without doing anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=325419:

> ... even if nothing is changing in the pixel output to the
>   screen, it's possible for the page to invalidate the entire rendered state
>   by e.g. dirtying the style of the document. Blink has no choice but to
>   recalc style, relayout, paint and composite at that point. Sometimes these
>   steps can be early-outed when nothing has effectively changed, but that's
>   hard to know for sure.

See also [Compositor Thread Architecture](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/compositor-thread-architecture) - seems like rAF triggers layer tree synchronization between the two compositor threads.